# How HTML/CSS pre-processors are made?

Tags: javascript, c#, html, compiler-construction, preprocessor

I'm a back-end developer and now I'm developing a webapp and needed to learn more about sass, css, html, js, to help my front-end partner.

As a C# develop, I like the syntax, with all the curly braces and semicolons, so I found SCSS very nice to use, than i started to search for a similar way to write HTML with all the nesting and C/C#/Java like syntax.

As I didn't find any html preprocessor that could be writen that way, I started to think about building one myself, but for now, I dont know much about how a pre-processor work.

I started to read some things about how a compiler works, but for now I just don't know how to start building it.

The precompiled language would look something like this, much simmilar to sass:

```
html{
  head{
     meta{}
     title{
       Title of the page
     }
  }
  body{
     //Comments like this
     @var variable = 10;
     h1{}
     ul{
        @for(i = 0; i<=variable; i++){
           li{
              @(i * variable);
           }
        }
     }
     @import "footer.html";
  }
}
```

Or maybe if there is a way to customize the Sass language/preprocessor to make ir generate the html using its syntax.

Comment: What you have described is a web template engine (or "templating engine"), which normally is supposed to work server-side.

Comment: I don't know how such a pre-processor will benefit you. CSS syntax  is not hierarchical, so a pre-processor there has a value. But HTML is hierarchical by nature. And constructs like loops and imports already exists in ASP.NET.

Comment: Almost, right, i use Razor while developing with ASP.Net and for dynamic pages ok, its awesome, but I wanted something simmilar but for static web pages, só i cold maintein it easier and generate the html files.

Comment: Replace html{ with <html> etc. I dont see the need for that.

Comment: If you want to create it dynamically see http://php.net